# Check if data already exists on a lot of data

Tags: cassandra, cql

I get csv files, read these files and write them to Cassandra. I do this for alot of data (roughly 10 million lines per day) The files itself are fairly small (from 100 to 1000 lines)

What I want to do is checking before i write them to the database, if the primary key I'm about to insert, already exists.

I know I can do it with `Select count(*) from table where primary key1 = something and key2 is something else`.

But this is slow, I want to check for an entire file in 1 go if its going to effect data that is already in Cassandra, and I want(need) it to be fast.
Is there a way to achieve what I want? (or something similar, like checking per batch if its going to affect rows)

Comment: Could you post you table schema? Specifically which key is a partition and which is clustering (if any) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use IF NOT EXIST in INSERT Statements and IF EXIST in UPDATE Statements. The performance is better than counting all rows but, in compare to insert, without checking, slow. Cassandra has to check all nodes for existing primary keys.

Documentation for INSERT: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/insert_r.html

and for UPDATE: 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html

Comment: This does not provide me any feedback what items did not get inserted right?

Comment: You will get a true or false. Create a lightweight script. You create, for each line, a CQL Command and then you can log the false with line numbers.

Comment: It actually makes sense, it does work but I think its way to slow. if the numbers in the database increase the IF NOT EXISTS takes up to much time. I will keep this in mind as it does what I want, but a little bit to slow.

Comment: The write request for each line won't be the problem. Cassandra is optimized for writes. The IF NOT EXIST will result in read write request in Cassandra. Maybe not the best performance but better than count(*) on all rows.

Comment: I know its not the write itself. IF NOT EXISTS is slow because it has to look up the primary key (makes sense it has to do this of course) i just hoped it would be faster.